# Get list ofTwoLetterISOLanguageName from list of EnglishName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a list of languages in english form:

```
German
English
French
...
```

I want to get:

```
DE
EN
FR
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string, string>()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to take the complete list of neutral (language-only) cultures, join that with your English names list, and then project that:

```
var languageCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
var twoLetterNames = from culture in languageCultures
                     join englishName in englishNames
                       on culture.EnglishName equals englishName
                     select culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

If you do this regularly, you might want to build a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
var cultureByLanguage = languageCultures.ToDictionary(x => x.EnglishName);
```

or:

```
var twoLetterIsoByLanguage = languageCultures.ToDictionary
    (x => x.EnglishName,
     x => TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
```